# Kafka dead letter queue pattern

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am working on a Kafka project in which one of the requirement is to implement a dead letter queue pattern.

The producer sends a record in a topic based on an Avro schema and is working fine and consumer works fine if I send a record based on schema. I am facing below 2 issues

> 1. When I send a dummy data from console producer to the same topic which is not as per schema then the consumer stops consuming any
>    messages even if the messages are based on Avro schema. It starting
>    working fine if I restart the containers( I am using confluent all in
>    one docker compose)
> 2. I am assuming that if the message is not as per avro schema consumer would throw an exception and that would be the place I could
>    redirect the message to dead letter queue for further processing but
>    this does not happen.

Below is the code that I am working on. It does not throw any exception. Any suggestions ? thanks

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecordBuilder;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Header;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.internals.RecordHeader;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import example.avro.Person;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig;


/**
 * 
 */
public class KafkaAvroMessageConsumer2 implements Runnable {

    
    private static final String KAFKA_SERVER_ADDRESS = "localhost:9092";
    private static final String SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8081";
    private static final String CONSUMER_GROUP_ID = "customer-message-consumer-group-1";
    final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaAvroMessageConsumer2.class.getSimpleName());
    private int consumerID;
    private String groupID;
    private String topicName ;
    private Consumer<String, GenericRecord> consumer;
    
    public KafkaAvroMessageConsumer2(int consumerId, String topicName, String groupID) {
        this.consumerID = consumerId;
        this.topicName = topicName;
        this.groupID = groupID;

        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_SERVER_ADDRESS);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupID);
        properties.put("schema.registry.url", SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        properties.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);

        this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);

    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topicName));
        System.out.println("polling....");
        try {
            while (true) {
                
                    final ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                    try {
                    for (final ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record : records) {
                        System.out.println(record.value());
                        // System.out.println(record.value().getFirstName().toString());
                    Person person = (Person) SpecificData.get().deepCopy(Person.SCHEMA$, record.value());
                        System.out.println(person.getFirstName());
                        // System.out.println(record.value().getAddress());
                        System.out.println(this.consumerID);
                        System.out.println(person.getId());
                    }
                    consumer.commitAsync();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                    // push the record to dead letter queue
                    log.info("INSIDE catch block");
                    
//                  System.out.println("INSIDE CATCH BLOCK");
                e.printStackTrace();

//              List <Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
//              e.
//              headers.add(new RecordHeader("website", "baeldung.com".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
//              ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord <>("baeldung", null, "message", "Hello World", headers);
//              
                }
            }

        } catch (WakeupException exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    
    public void shutdown() {
        System.out.println("Shutting down");
        consumer.wakeup();
      }
    
    
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int numConsumers = 3;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        
        final String TOPIC_NAME = "person";
        final String groupID = "multi-thread-2";
        final List<KafkaAvroMessageConsumer2> consumers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numConsumers; i++) {
            KafkaAvroMessageConsumer2 consumer = new KafkaAvroMessageConsumer2(i, TOPIC_NAME, groupID);
            consumers.add(consumer);
            executor.submit(consumer);
        }
        
         Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  for (KafkaAvroMessageConsumer2 consumer : consumers) {
                    consumer.shutdown();
                  }
                }
              });
    }
    

}
```